# Sending Post request on a button click generates XMLHttpRequest error in Flutter Web Application

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter application below generates XMLHttpRequest error when the button is clicked.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
 }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 HomePage() : super();
 @override
 _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Flutter WebView '),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: TextButton(
      child: Text('Push me'),
      onPressed: save,
    ),
  ),
 );
}

void save() async {
 var sendString =
    '{"name":"MyCompany","address1":"100 main ","address2":"Apt 202"}';
 final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080/employers/nameAddress'),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'ContentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: sendString,
 );
 print(response.statusCode);
 print(response.contentLength);
 print(response.reasonPhrase);
 print(response.body);
}
}
```

The error generated is as follows:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 909:28    get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 71:22        <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1613:54               runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 155:18         handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 707:44         handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 736:13        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 533:           [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11         _cancelAndValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1219:7                  <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14 
_checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37307:58                <fn>
at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:5054:12)
at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:37670:16)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback 
(http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:37666:13)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:37526:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:37532:13)
at http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:33303:9
```

The following Dart application using the same save() function as above works fine without error.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
 save();
}

void save() async {
  var sendString =
  '{"name":"MyCompany","address1":"100 main ","address2":"Apt 202"}';
 final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080/employers/nameAddress'),
  headers: <String, String>{
  'ContentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: sendString,
 );
 print(response.statusCode);
 print(response.contentLength);
 print(response.reasonPhrase);
 print(response.body);
```

}

I used the following Dart server to test both the Flutter app and Dart app. Server simply responds to any request it receives:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart' as shelf;
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;

void main() async {
  print('server starting on 8080');
  httpServer = await io.serve(process, 'localhost', 8080);
}

var httpServer;
FutureOr<shelf.Response> process(shelf.Request request) {
 print('got request');
 return shelf.Response.ok('Got request');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this you set the **Cors** in **header** section :

```
return {
     headers: {
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
     "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true", 
     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(body)
};
```

Comment: Used BrowserClient for post transaction.
Also added CORS headers on server to fixe the issue.