# I am getting error(Error: XMLHttpRequest error.) while I am running flutter application using http post request

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart, post

[I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V18FN.png)

[here is code I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLNf2.png)

Comment: Try my answer here hope it's helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68493792/13997210

Comment: yeah tried but it didn't work

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Click ok the https://i.stack.imgur.com/V18FN.png

Comment: Just use `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when making a get request and solved it by adding the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*" to the response of my python flask backend. So basically i updated not my flutter application, but the server it made the request to.
as I use python flask it looked like this:

```
response = jsonify(rList)
response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") 
return response
```