# XMLHttpRequest error when loging in on flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a login API for a web app in Flutter. Postman and all other apps  works fine, but when running through Flutter the `XMLHttpRequest error` occurs. Here's my code:

```
login() async {
var url = '${Urls.url}auth/signin';
var headers = {
  'x-api-key': 'x-api-key',
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
};

// print(headers);
 var datas = {
  'userId': nameEditingController.text,
  'userPwd': passwordEditingController.text
};

// print(datas);
var request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.bodyFields = datas;

request.headers.addAll(headers);

try {
  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  print(response.statusCode);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String data = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    var jsonR = json.decode(data);
    _localStorage['token'] = jsonR['data']['token'];
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Wrapper()),
        (route) => false);
  } else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
} catch (e) {
  
  data = 'Server is not accepting your request';
  print(e);
}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: what about your base url? Does it contain `/` end of the URL?

Comment: i think you also forget to encode your data.

Comment: Check and include `CORS` headers if not included for the API.

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68493792/13997210) answer hope its help to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is something you should do on your server config you should enable CORS
by adding following to headers (every one you need):

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With,content-type"
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
```

also if you are passing any parameter in header the server side should be expecting it

Comment: So this is a server issue? I don't have access to the servers. Devs said they are not receiving any requests to the server. I can sometimes log in when using a VPN.

Comment: @JishnuKSanjeevan On the web when you try to do an api call, the browser make a preflight request to check if a certain method is allowed by the server. If the server hasn't that method inside the value of the header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` the browser won't make the api call at all. On the server you should see in the logs a request made with the method `OPTIONS`. That's the preflight request. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)