# how to solve XMLHttpRequest error on flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, xmlhttprequest

when i run my code i get the following error, my app is for downloading sound of video from youtube.

error

**Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57539/2eLyP6sNDkg=/ws
XMLHttpRequest error.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'thumbnail')
at YoutubeMP3._YoutubeMP3State.new.getInfo (http://localhost:62257/packages/utube_mp3/YoutubeMP3.dart.lib.js:507:40)
at getInfo.throw ()
at http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:40652:38
at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:40508:58)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:35445:33)
at handleError (http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:36033:51)
at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:36059:17)
at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:35905:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:35944:31)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:40808:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:40814:13)
at http://localhost:62257/dart_sdk.js:36279:9**

function getinfo

```
 //

 Future<void> getInfo() async {
   insertBody(videoURL.text);
   setState(() {
     progress = "";
     status = "Download";
     downloadsuccess = false;
     isDownloading = false;
     isFetching = true;
     fetchSuccess = false;
   });
   try {
     var response = await http.post("https://www.y2mate.com/fr22",
         body: body, headers: headers);

     video = Result.convertResult(response.body);
     setState(() {
       isFetching = false;
       fetchSuccess = true;
     });
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
     setState(() {
       isFetching = true;
       fetchSuccess = false;
     });
   }
   print("${video.thumbnail}\n${video.audioName}\n${video.vid}\n${video.id}");
 }
```

Comment: Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68493792/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: thank you but still not working

Comment: Now what was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You error message indicates that getInfo is trying to access `(null).thumbnail`. It's likely your last print statement. If Result.convertResult() fails with an exception and video=null, execution moves to your catch() block then afterward tries to print "video.thumbnail" (which doesn't exist)

You could try wrapping your last print statement with `if (video!=null)` or move it inside your try{} block.

Comment: i rewrite the last print statement to print("error");
and i get it when run my program , what can i do for get the correct result ?